# Are these specs (VPS) good enough to run a Tor relay?

Tags: relays, bandwidth, guard-node

I want to run a bunch of Tor relays, and so plan to buy 10 $5 VPS's from a company called Beastnode. I have had an amazing experience with this company for game servers and websites in the past, so I hope that it'll be fast.

The specs of the VPS I plan to buy is as follows:
• 512MB of RAM
• 25GB of SSD space (though I doubt this matters?)
• 2000GB (2TB) of Bandwidth.

I don't really understand all this bandwidth/s thing on Tor relays, as that 2TB is how much I can use before having to pay bandwidth fees. Is 2TB enough bandwidth overall, and how can I limit how much my relay uses OVERALL (or individually, if you have any recommendations)?

P.S. I would like my relays to be a fast relay.

Comment: I assume those 2TB are per month. Do you know how fast the network connection is?

Comment: You can download various sized files on the site to test for yourself, but in my experience they are very fast. And yes, it is per month.

Comment: Beastnode don't allow you to "contain any kind of proxy server or other traffic relaying programs" on their services. Check their T&Cs under Acceptable Use.

Comment: There's [a list](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs) of which hosts and ISPs support/accept Tor. SolarVPS has similar specs for the same price.

Answer (score 2):

Those specs don't include CPU speed, number of cores, network speed. 512MB of RAM may be a bit tight.

You can use the following directives in your torrc to influence the bandwidth usage of your relay:

- [`RelayBandwidthRate`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#RelayBandwidthRate) - Limits the average incoming bandwidth usage for *relayed traffic* on this node to the specified number of bytes per second.
- [`RelayBandwidthBurst`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#RelayBandwidthBurst) - Allow up to this much for short periods.
- [`AccountingMax`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AccountingMax) - Never send more than the specified number of bytes in a given accounting period, or receive more than that number in the period.
- [`AccountingStart`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AccountingStart) - Specify how long accounting periods last. If month is given, each accounting period runs from the time HH:MM on the dayth day of one month to the same day and time of the next.

Your provider will count data in and out separately, so you can *relay* 1 TB/month, which is **364 KB/sec**.

If you set this as your `RelayBandwidthRate` then you will only get to your 1 TB if your relay is constantly saturated. This is unlikely.
If you set your `RelayBandwidthRate` too high, you will hit your `AccountingMax` too soon and your relay will hibernate, which you would want to avoid.

I would set
`AccountingMax` and `AccountingStart` to 0.95 TB / month, so you never get to pay overage charges.
`RelayBandwidthRate` to about 150% or 200% of the calculated 364 KB, so that would be 600 KB/s or so. If you hit your `AccountingMax`, turn it down a bit. If you don't hit it in your 3rd month, turn it up a bit.
`RelayBandwidthBurst` to 90% of your actual maximum speed.